# allowing sudo to delete certain files

Tags: centos, sudo

I would like to allow to delete certain files in /tmp directory to sudo users. I have added the `Allow_Cmnd /usr/sbin/userdel` for sudo users but this does not delete all /tmp files associated with the user.

So how shall I tweak the sudoers to allow them to delete certain files in /tmp directory only. I googled a bit but learned that regex may be be application at this. I tried couple of tweaks but its not working for me.

I would like the users to have ability to execute command such as

```
find /tmp -uid 10002 | grep joeuser | xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: Why the `grep joeuser`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do is write a script that does what you want. You can do
extensive sanity checking in there, check if the user is doing only what they
are allowed, and so on. And then only allow that script to be ran from sudo.

Alternatively you can also allow them to run
the command as you described it: `/bin/bash -c "find /tmp -uid 10002
| grep joeuser | xargs rm -rf"`, or even simpler `find /tmp -uid 10002
-path \*joeuser\* -delete`.

As pointed out already, using `xargs` this way is not a good idea. You can either use `find -print0 | xargs -0`, or my personal recommendation is: `find /tmp -uid 10002 -path \*joeuser\* -depth -exec rm -rf {} +`. If your version of `find` does not support the `+`, you may use `\;` instead.

Comment: first option with xargs is dangerous because it can easily be tricked to delete anything. It does not handle files and dirs with spaces properly due to IFS being space so you should use find -print0 and xargs -0

Comment: but without xargs or -exec , how to delete the directories. the -delete only removes files.

Comment: @chandank: This is not true. `find -delete` deletes everything that matches. It also implies `-depth`, so it will delete the innermost paths before deleting a parent directory.

Comment: I may be doing something wrong. But  

`find . -name myname -delete
find: cannot delete `./myname': Directory not empty`.

Comment: @chandank: I see what you mean. `-delete` does delete directories, but does not delete directories **recursively**.

Comment: Also, `find -path foo* -delete` will first match and delete everything inside the directory, as opposed to `-name` which would only match the directory.

Comment: I did it using -exec rm -rf {}+ and I guess this is best option that I could use as of now. Thanks for your all comments.

Answer (score 1):

I believe a well-written script will be your best option. However, this really depends on the overall goal and how well the design is planned... Do you want the files in /tmp to be deleted that belong to the user executing the script or should the script accept parameters for UID and username?

There are obvious security concerns and you need to be very careful. During your testing, I would not institute the actual delete, but log (output) the files that "would" be deleted if the delete code was in place. I would then test about 3 more times to be certain.

Lastly, the other option depending on your needs would be to write a more generic script and schedule it to run at a certain date/time via cron to automate the process.

BTW:

**/usr/sbin/userdel is NOT the command you want. That is for deleting local user accounts.**

-Brendan

Comment: @Brendan, Thanks for pointing out. Yes I want a user to delete the /tmp file entries of other users using UID and user name. In my setup I want a non priviledged user should have just enough power to delete the other users and their /tmp files only. As of now using sudoer file and sudo command they are able to user account but not able to delete the /tmp file.

Comment: Is it the /tmp dir on the main filesystem or something like /home/user/tmp? The command for removing files is 'rm'. That would need to be added to the line in the sudoers file to grant access to that application.

Comment: this is filesystem's /tmp directory where all gconf and other GUI related temp files are stored.

Comment: You'll need to grant the sudo user access to rm and develop the script to handle the deletion and test, test, test, and test again before it goes into production. Follow the advice I posted previously and comment out the 'rm' commands and output what files would be deleted so you can make sure the script is grabbing the correct files.